# X86 assembly IDIV and CQTO

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, x86-64

I want to achieve these function:
`a=300;
b=3000;
b=b/a;
print b;`

And i write these assembly code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <lib.s>
.bss
a:  .long 128
b:  .long 128
c:  .double 64
zzz:    .long 128
.data

FINT:   .string "%d\n"
.text
.global main
main:
push    $300
pop a
push    $3000
pop b
push    b
push    a
pop %rbx
pop %rax
cqo
idivq   %rbx
push    %rax
pop b
push    b
pop %rsi
mov $FINT, %rdi
mov $0, %rax
call    printf
call exit
```

but it output 0, i just can't understand this. It should be 10.
Any help is appreciate! Thanks!

Comment: Step through the code line by line in a debugger. Did you calculate the zero? Or did you calculate 10? If you calculated zero, where did it come from? If you calculated 10, then figure out why it is printing as zero.

Comment: The %d in the format string may need a prefix to indicate it's printing a 64 bit value, although this should cause a 10 to print as a zero. The code could use mov instructions instead of all those push and pop instructions. Try something simple like mov $FINT,%rdi / mov $10,%rsi / call printf to see if that works.